# Array as module parameter

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

How to pass a constant array as a module parameter?

I want to build a shift register width different shift widths. The possible shift widths should be definable via a module parameter. I tried something like the following, but this not working.

```
module ShiftReg
#(
  SHIFT_WIDTH = '{1, 2, 4, 8},
  WIDTH = $clog2($size(SHIFT_WIDTH))
)
(
  ...
  input  logic [WIDTH-1:0] shift_rate_i,
  ...
);
  ...
endmodule
```

This results in following error message:

```
** Error: shift_reg.sv(3): Illegal concatenation of an unsized constant.
```

Is such a generic construction of a shift register with different widths possible in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 1):

Not every simulator supports arrayed parameters. For those that do, the array needs to be defined with an array identifier (ex: `[]`, `[SIZE]`) and a bit width for the entries; `int SHIFT_WIDTH [] = '{1, 2, 4, 8}` should work.

I tried different combinations on [EDAplaygroud](http://www.edaplayground.com). Queued arrays (`[$]`) was not accepted by any simulator. VCS supported `[]` arrayed parameters, but it does not accept it with `$size()` or `.size()` in a parameter definition. A fixed array size does work on VCS and Riviera-PRO. Declaring the size is an extra step, but it works.

```
module ShiftReg
#(
  SIZE = 4,
  int SHIFT_WIDTH [SIZE] = '{1, 2, 4, 8},
  WIDTH = $clog2(SIZE)
//WIDTH = $clog2($size(SHIFT_WIDTH)) // <-- this also works if SHIFT_WIDTH is a fixed size
)
(
  ...
  input  logic [WIDTH-1:0] shift_rate_i,
  ...
);
  ...
endmodule
```

Comment: Just a side question. Will this be synthesizable? I doubt that.

Comment: @sharvil111, it *could* synthesize ***if*** the synthesizer implemented it. Most synthesizers probably do not support it right now, but I cannot see any reason why it shouldn't. Just a matter of demand for the feature and time.

Comment: Yaa I agree. This **should** be made synthesizable. But obviously dynamic/queues arrays must not be accepted. Thanks for the clarification.